# Why does this alternative hypothesis test make a better statement vs the other?

Tags: statistics

I have a problem that is asking me to just set up a hypothesis test. Here is the background of the question: Suppose that the specificataions state that mean strength of welds should exceed $100$ $lb/in^2$; the inspection team decides to test $H_0: \mu=100$ versus $H_a:\mu\gt100$. Now I need to explain why this alternative hypotheseis would be a better choice than $H_a:\mu\lt 100$. But I don't really see the difference. Can someone explain this difference to me?